# How to update v-data-table data in real time?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am developing a node and electron application. I'm using vuetify to generate the table (v-data-table) that loads data from an oracle database.
The data changes according to the value of input, but the table does not update!

When input values change: **process.env.ANO_SEM** =  **input.val()**

then i call **loadData() function**

**process.env.ANO_SEM** is used as parameter for sql query in **getEventos() function**

My code:

```
 $('#input').keyup(e => {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            process.env.ANO_SEM = $('#input').val()
            loadData()
        }
 })

// Get data from BD
async function getEventos() {
    const sql = await fs
        .readFileSync(path.join(process.env.ROOT_PATH, 'src/db/sql/get-evento.sql'))
        .toString()
    return await db.getData(sql, [process.env.ANO_SEM])
}

async function loadData() {
    let data = await getEventos()
    console.log(data) // the data aways change, but the table never update
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        methods: {
            rowClick(idEvento) {
                require(path.join(process.env.CTRL_PATH, './evento/evento-ctrl.js'))(
                    window.$,
                    idEvento
                )
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                selectedItem: 'Sample',
                pagination: {
                    sortBy: 'ID'
                },
                headers: [
                    { text: 'ID', value: 'ID', align: 'center', width: '10%' },
                    { text: 'Descrição', value: 'DESCRICAO', align: 'left', width: '60%' },
                    { text: 'Período', value: 'PERIODO', align: 'left', width: '20%' },
                    {
                        text: 'Data Impressão',
                        value: 'DATA_IMPRESSAO',
                        align: 'left',
                        width: '10%'
                    }
                ],
                eventos: data
            }
        }
    })
}
```

my html:

```html
<div id="app" class="table-eventos">
        <v-app>
            <v-data-table
                :headers="headers"
                :items="eventos"
                :rows-per-page-items="[100]"
                item-key="name"
                class="elevation-1"
            >
                <!-- :pagination.sync="pagination" -->
                <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                    <tr @click="rowClick(props.item.ID)">
                        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.ID }}</td>
                        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.DESCRICAO }}</td>
                        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.PERIODO }}</td>
                        <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.DATA_IMPRESSAO }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </v-data-table>
        </v-app>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I took the liberty of setting up the project structure with vue-cli and also added mock data and a text-field, let me know if you have any doubts, I'm pretty sure you'll get the point, clone the public repo, run

```
 npm install
```

and then

```
npm run serve
```

https://github.com/sdpotts93/vue-simple-table

Comment: Everyone agrees on this "Sometimes vue does not render your changes"

Comment: so updating the html with that loading attribute should make it work

Comment: nothing happened =(

https://imgur.com/a/yZE0SqN

You see, when the input value changes, the database data is changed too, but the table doesn't ...

Comment: I realize my answer was indeed kinda silly, didn't pay enough attention to the code, why do you mount your vue component again each time? This does look like code that won't do what you want to do, just mount it 1 time and play with your data

Comment: is there a reason for you to setup the app structure like that?

Comment: I'm new to Vue, I set it up this structure because I don't know how to change data after i built v-data-table

Comment: I haven't used electron but I just read this and it might help you out: https://dev.to/thomas_ph35/how-i-built-a-desktop-app-with-vue-in-minutes-1005, the thing is, if you want to use Vue, setup the whole app as a vue instance, don't use jquery outside with node and create a vue instance inside every time you load data, that kinda doesn't make sense, I understand you are new to Vue, try installing vue-cli and with 'vue create', setup the vue project stucture and work with that https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create

Comment: I really like Vue btw, have tried React and Angular, Vue is my fav but of course it's a personal choice

Comment: Thanks, i'll check

Comment: if you can, share your project, I'd be interesting to check it out

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change props :item. Your example solved my problem! Thank you very much @Sdpotts93

Answer (score 0):

So basically what happens in your code is you load your vue into #app, this get rendered and your new #app element looks different - but still get linked to your new vue and rendered - but this time vue somehow fails.

long story short - put your render element into a static template that you can rerender:

i made a simple example from your sketch:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
const mockData = Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) => [{
      DATA_IMPRESSAO: `mock${i}`,
      PERIODO: `mock${i}`,
      DESCRICAO: `mock${i}`,
      ID: `mock${i}`,
  }])
  
  let nonReactiveIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*mockData.length)
 setInterval(() =>
new Vue({
  template: "#example",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  mounted() {
    nonReactiveIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*mockData.length)
    console.log("mounted", nonReactiveIndex);
    
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: "ID", value: "ID", align: "center", width: "10%" },
        { text: "Descrição", value: "DESCRICAO", align: "left", width: "60%" },
        { text: "Período", value: "PERIODO", align: "left", width: "20%" },
        {
          text: "Data Impressão",
          value: "DATA_IMPRESSAO",
          align: "left",
          width: "10%"
        }
      ],
      eventos: mockData[nonReactiveIndex]
      
    };
  },
  
}
).$mount('#app'), 2000)
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

    <div id="app" class="table-eventos">
      
    </div>
    
    <template id="example">
    <v-app>
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="eventos"
          :rows-per-page-items="[100]"
          item-key="name"
          class="elevation-1"
        >
          <!-- :pagination.sync="pagination" -->
          <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <tr @click="rowClick(props.item.ID)">
              <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.ID }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.DESCRICAO }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.PERIODO }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.DATA_IMPRESSAO }}</td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-app>
    </template>
```

---

### It is a better design to implement everything into the vue component and let vue handle reactivity:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
const mockData = Array.from({length: 100}, (_, i) => [{
      DATA_IMPRESSAO: `mock${i}`,
      PERIODO: `mock${i}`,
      DESCRICAO: `mock${i}`,
      ID: `mock${i}`,
  }])
  

new Vue({
  template: "#example",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  mounted() {
    
    console.log("mounted", this.reactiveIndex);
    
  },
  data() {
    return {
      reactiveIndex : Math.floor(Math.random()*mockData.length),
      headers: [
        { text: "ID", value: "ID", align: "center", width: "10%" },
        { text: "Descrição", value: "DESCRICAO", align: "left", width: "60%" },
        { text: "Período", value: "PERIODO", align: "left", width: "20%" },
        {
          text: "Data Impressão",
          value: "DATA_IMPRESSAO",
          align: "left",
          width: "10%"
        }
      ],
     
      
    };
  },
  computed: {
      eventos(){ return mockData[this.reactiveIndex] }
  },
  methods: {
    load(){
      this.reactiveIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*mockData.length)
      console.log(this.reactiveIndex)
    }
  }
}
).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

    <div id="app" class="table-eventos">
      
    </div>
    
    <template id="example">
    <v-app>
        <v-btn @click="load">load</v-btn>
        
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="eventos"
          :rows-per-page-items="[100]"
          item-key="name"
          class="elevation-1"
        >
          <!-- :pagination.sync="pagination" -->
          <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <tr @click="rowClick(props.item.ID)">
              <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.ID }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.DESCRICAO }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.PERIODO }}</td>
              <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.DATA_IMPRESSAO }}</td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-app>
    </template>
```

Comment: don't you think this is not ideal? Wouldn't it be better to use just vue? I guess it could work, just read this https://forum.vuejs.org/t/mounting-a-vue-instance-to-a-dynamically-created-element/37063/3

Comment: @Sdpotts93 yes it is best to just put the response into a data property and let vue reactive handle data changes - i will add this solution, i just tried to point out what happens and how to avoid this behaviour even if for any reason one is in this design decision

Comment: Erro at line: vuetify: new Vuetify() // TypeError: Vuetify is not a constructor